# How to debug database project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, triggers, sqlclr

Ok, I'm using Quartz.NET, I have a table, when the database in that table change (after inserted, updated) I have to download a file from url, then parse that file, and insert data to another table....

I do all of this in SQL CLR Trigger. Because I dont know when the data is changed. And it is changed by other application/web service, not the current application.

So, again, I have an SQL CLR Trigger and I want to debug it when it's deploying.
I found an article here, but noluck. I cannot find a way to create the test script in step 3
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165052(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165052%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
It seems that my Visual Studio 2013 has no option for "Set as Default Debug Script." or did I miss something?

Anybody here have debugged with Database Project?
Please walk me though this, or help me with any suggestion.

SQL CLR Trigger

```
public class Triggers
{
    [SqlTrigger(Name = "AfterMarketSessionInserted", Target = "MarketSession",
        Event = "FOR INSERT")]
    public static void AfterMarketSessionInserted()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM INSERTED", connection);

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            // ... SOME CODE THAT NEED TO BE DEBUGGED.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have an SQL CLR Trigger : - First question: Why?

Comment: Because I need to write C# code to call to other service from other application's layers.

Comment: "write C# code to call to other service from other application's layers." - My advice: just don't do that in a trigger.

Comment: Ok, I'm using Quartz.NET, I have a table, when the database in that table change (after inserted, updated) I have to download a file from url, then parse that file, and insert data to another table....
I do all of this in SQL CLR Trigger. Because I dont know when the data is changed. And it is changed by other application/web service, not the current application.